# Which .Net ORM supports sql like batch insert/update/delete?

Tags: c#, t-sql, orm

Which ORM supports sql like batch insert/update/delete:

```
var user=new UserInfoFields();
var update=user.Update().Set
(
   user.Field1=1,
   user.Field2="xxxx"
).Where(user.Name=="Jim" && user.Enable==true);

update.Excute();
```

The corresponding T-sql is:

```
UPDATE UserInfo 
SET 
    Field1=1,
    Field2="xxxx"
WHERE Name='Jim' and Enable=1
```

Comment: (Most, if not all) ORM's are **not** designed to handle bulk operations. If you want bulk operations, use a suitable bulk component, or do it in your database directly (e.g. using a stored proc or something like that)

Comment: @marc_s:Thank you for your answer. I agree with you about ORM are not designed to handle bulk operations,but sometimes this way is very useful if we need to support multiple type databases,And i found that LLBLgen support operations like this,but his API is not fluent.

Comment: Yes, it's convenient - and good practice. For those cases, I typically recommend encapsulating the functionality into a stored proc and executing that sproc from your ORM (e.g. `DataContext` for Linq-to-SQL or similar)

Comment: Api isn't fluent yet, we're working on that at the moment (api update for v2.6 and up. ), which is a fluent api targeting our native query api, similar to what our linq provider does.

Comment: @Frans Bouma:Thanks for your work,i am very interested in LLBLGen provide these feature,and i hope LLBLGen support Lambda style batch insert/update/delete,i think that will be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP ActiveRecord has something like this, but that's PHP. Linq2SQL can be extended to perform simpler batch updates/deletes, but it's not "stock" behavior. Here's the link to an article on the topic: http://www.aneyfamily.com/terryandann/post/2008/04/Batch-Updates-and-Deletes-with-LINQ-to-SQL.aspx. I know for a fact that NHibernate has nothing like this built in, but again, you can extend the Linq provider, and NH also allows HQL and SQL queries as strings, including batch updates/deletes (only problem is they're "magic strings" that are not compiler-checked).

This kind of behavior really goes against what an ORM is designed to do. ORMs exist not to provide compiler-checked queries for all possible SQL operations, but to provide "black-box" encapsulated logic for CRUD operations of single instances of objects, for instance, turning a request for an object into SQL that retrieves the necessary data and hydrates the object. Batch and bulk operations are not their forte by any means.

Comment: http://ayende.com/Blog/2006/09/16/BatchingSupportInNHibernate.aspx - You don't require the use of HQL or SQL Queries to do batching in NHibernate. You can select a bunch of objects, modify them and commit hem back in a batch with LINQ.

Comment: The behavior you describe changes how NHibernate sends individual insert/update/delete requests to the server; it does not provide for a "mass update" Linq feature as described in the OP. NH will simply cache session updates on individual objects until it has the required batch size or the session is flushed, then send them all in a single compound command. It reduces round trips, not query count; each command still operates on one object (the obvious exception being select queries which are not central to the discussion).

Comment: Here's a working link to Ayende's blog post: http://ayende.com/blog/1686/batching-support-in-nhibernate

Answer (score 5):

Checkout BLToolkit -> [BLToolkit Linq Extensions - Update](http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc.LinqExtensions.ashx#Update_2)

```
db.Employee
    .Where(e => e.Title == "Spectre")
    .Update(e => new Northwind.Employee
    {
        Title = "Commander"
    });
```

or

```
db.Employee
    .Where(e => e.Title == "Spectre")
    .Set(e => e.Title, "Commander")
    .Update();
```

=

```
UPDATE
    [e]
SET
    [Title] = 'Commander'
FROM
    [Employees] [e]
WHERE
    [e].[Title] = 'Spectre'
```

Been using it for 2-3 years now and its great :D

First read this though -> 
[High Level Vision, Global Architecture Strategy & Concept Model Design](http://www.bltoolkit.net/Doc.LinqModel.ashx)

Comment: Thanks!This is the effect which I most want.

Comment: Downvoting because the domain isn't active any longer.  Probably not a good tool to use since it's not maintained.

Answer (score 1):

Most of ORMs I know lacks the bulk updates functionality, if you prefer working with EnityFramework like me you can use the [Entity Framework Extended Library](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) wich extends many functionalities upon EntityFramework including bulk updates and deletes and Future queries.